# Ajax dynamic select from 2 fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am doing bank account validation using ajax dynamic select. onkeyup after the acc number is entered, it runs a check from external file. Right now, I can only check the account number, I want it to be able to check the bank and acc number. I simple want to GET the value of  bank and account to be used for the validation in validate_acc.php.

```
    <script>
function dynamic_Select3(ajax_page, account) {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: ajax_page,
data: "ch=" + account,
//data: "ch2=" + bank,
dataType: "html",
//dataType: "text/html", //<--UPDATE: DELETING THIS LINE FIXES EVERYTHING
//<--UPDATE2: DON'T DELETE; REPLACE "test/html" with "html"
success: function(html){       $("#txtResult3").html(html); }
}); 
}
</script>
```

my html form

```
<td class="body_text_normal_npt">Select your Bank</td>
    <td><span class="body_text_normal_npt">
      <select name="bank" id="bank">
        <option value="Select Values" selected="selected">-------------------------------</option>
        <?php

$sql4="SELECT bankName FROM banks WHERE status = 'active'";
$banks = $mydb->query($sql4) or die(mysqli_error($mydb));
$row_banks = mysqli_fetch_assoc($banks);
$totalRows_banks = mysqli_num_rows($banks);

do {  

?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_banks['bankName']?>"><?php echo $row_banks['bankName']?></option>
        <?php

} while ($row_banks = mysqli_fetch_assoc($banks));

  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($banks);

  if($rows > 0) {

      mysqli_data_seek($banks, 0);

      $row_banks = mysqli_fetch_assoc($banks);

  }

?>
      </select>
    </span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="body_text_normal_npt">Acc Number</td>
    <td><p>
      <input name="account" type="text" id="account" size="25" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" onKeyUp="dynamic_Select3('validate_acc.php', this.value)" />
    </p>
</td>
  </tr>
```

The validation page

```
//$bank= $_GET['modepayment'];
$bank= $_GET['ch2'];
$accnum = $_GET['ch'];

 $query_bcode = "SELECT bankCode,abbr FROM banks WHERE bankName = '$bank'";
$bcode = $mydb->query($query_bcode) or die(mysqli_error($mydb));
$row_bcode = $bcode->fetch_assoc();

$bankCode = $row_bcode['bankCode'];
//echo $bankCode;
//echo $accnum;

$json = file_get_contents("https://api.bank.codes/ng-nuban/?format=json&api_key=2d112c21e1c5844f*******154&bank=$bankCode&nuban=$accnum");
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible to try this? You can have multiple parameters in this way.

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "ajax_page",
  method: "POST",
  data: { ch: account, ch2: bank},
  dataType: "html"
});
```

Code is based on an example from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/